# How to share my screen via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, display, lan, screen-sharing

Is there any software that allows sharing one's screen through WiFi?

I am particularly interested in having that capability between PC and Mac computers.

What this will allow is for any computer in a room to display their screen on a projector, as long as they are connected to WiFi. That is the main setting I need this functionality for.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Note: This is not a VNC situation. I don't need to share any control. I simply want to share my screen. Like one can do in Skype, but without going through the internet. Simply using the local WiFi.

Comment: Why not use VNC or Remote Desktop?  You dont have to share control.

Comment: You could just stream it...

Comment: You can use VNC without using the internet. Just use your local IP.